# Which Stack Exchange Site should I ask questions that will reach web designers?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I want to ask questions that web designers (Those folks who can make pixels dance with CSS and HTML) will read. I'm not seeing a Stack Exchange specific for them.

Which would be the closest? Webmasters? Graphic Design?

--Edit--

Sorry, I realized I wasn't being clear. Specifically I wanted to ask questions about the *business* of Web Designers. Stuff like "What are things to look for in a designer's portfolio when looking to hire?", "What are the best resources for hiring the right designers?", etc.

Comment: Regarding your edit, it's highly likely that your example questions are off-topic throughout the SE network, since they are highly subjective "poll" questions. However, you could try [Startups](http://answers.onstartups.com/) or possibly http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ , although check the [Six Guidelines](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice) first.

Comment: @Robert, while I broadly agree with your assessment I think that there are, potentially, **two** area 51 sites worth a look to discuss those issues: [Developer Team Leads](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20300/developer-team-leads) and [Interviewing & Recruiting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13418/interviewing-recruiting). Though I'd more happily recommend the latter, given the edit.

Comment: @David: Both of those sites are still in the definition phase.

Comment: @Robert, true; my...language drifted a little in my response to you. In my answer I suggested they were maybe 'worth following,' which is rather more accurate than my above comment. Oops. +1 for paying more attention to my wording... :)

Answer (score 2):

Once upon a time the appropriate resource was [Doctype](http://www.doctype.com), but I've not seen it mentioned in recent months. I'd suggest that you ask questions related to the *mechanisms* of your design (JS/HTML/CSS...) on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) itself, since that site attracts many html designers and devs (even if, strictly speaking, web-design might be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/faq/)),and questions related to the *user interface itself*, and design, on [User Experience](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-experience).

---

Reference:

- [Stackoverflow Blog entry detailing Doctype's admission to the 'League of (Web) Justice.'](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/stack-overflow-and-doctype/).

---

With regards to the edit:

> Specifically I wanted to ask questions about the business of Web Designers. Stuff like "What are things to look for in a designer's portfolio when looking to hire?", "What are the best resources for hiring the right designers?", etc.

<del>I'd suggest that for this kind of discussion [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) ***might*** be the better site to read, for discussions around the broad subject of 'how to hire a good programmer/designer.'</del> (The previous paragraph redacted in response to @Mark Trapp's comment, below). As to the question of 'best resources,' it's possible, though I'm following *neither*, that either [Developer Team Leads](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20300/developer-team-leads), or possibly [Interviewing & recruiting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13418/interviewing-recruiting), might be proposals worth following.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I clarified above.

Comment: @Drew, you did indeed, I've tried to revise my answer a little to offer something a little more useful to you.

Comment: This stuff isn't on-topic for Programmers.SE, but might be on-topic for GraphicDesign.SE. Not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange (yet).